# Transparency is gone while resizing (scaling) gif using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, scaling

I am re-sizing gif images using ffmpeg. My problem is that the transparency of image is not coming while re-sizing. How can I achieve transparency while re-sizing it?

My ffmpeg command is:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.gif-vf scale=320:240 output_converted_gif.gif
```

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: There is no need to show out put it scales the gif but lost the transperency .

Comment: The console output will have details of what ffmpeg's doing. Please paste.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `-filter_complex` flag to scale and preserve transparency, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif-vf -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=320:240, split [a][b]; [a] palettegen=reserve_transparent=on:transparency_color=ffffff [p]; [b][p] paletteuse" output_converted_gif.gif
```

See: https://superuser.com/a/1362406/1058900

Answer (score 1):

Does this get solved when you add +transdiff, as per the example here:
http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but still transperency is lost please give me an example that which command I should use.

Comment: This does not answer the question and would've been better as a comment.