# ffmpeg. transparency is not preserved when zooming

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.gif -pix_fmt rgb32 -r 10 -s 150x150 2.gif
```

Transparency is not preserved when zooming.
how to solve it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603464/transparency-is-gone-while-resizing-scaling-gif-using-ffmpeg), which [references this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1362352/how-do-i-resize-an-animated-gif-and-keep-transparency/1362406#1362406).

Comment: What do you mean with "zooming"?