# ffmpeg: pad filter with transparent background for GIF input/output?

Tags: ffmpeg, animated-gif

I'm trying to pad the GIF source to a square thumbnail and the extended area should be transparent.

*(image source: https://store.steampowered.com/app/2113680/The_Dot/)*

[image]

To achieve the goal, I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i ./test/source.gif -filter_complex "[0]scale=255:144[s1];[s1]pad=256:256:0:-56:blue[s2];[s2]split[s3][s4];[s3]palettegen=reserve_transparent=on:transparency_color=blue[p];[s4][p]paletteuse[s5]" -map [s5] -loop 0  ./test/output.gif -y
```

1. `[0]scale=255:144[s1]` 
    First I scale down the image.
2. `[s1]pad=256:256:0:-56:blue[s2]` 
    Then pad the image with an uncommon background color: `blue`
3. `[s2]split[s3][s4]` 
    And I split to two streams. One for `palettegen` and another for `paletteuse`.
4. `[s3]palettegen=reserve_transparent=on:transparency_color=blue[p]` 
    Generate the color palette that indicates `blue` as the `transparency_color`
5. `[s4][p]paletteuse[s5]`  
    Use the new color palette for output. The padded image with `blue` background color should be treated as a transparent background.

But the output animated GIF still has a visible blue background color no matter if I put the `paletteuse` at first or in the end.

[image]

Related posts:

- [Making GIFs with ffmpeg: what does "transparency_color" do?](https://superuser.com/questions/1654980/making-gifs-with-ffmpeg-what-does-transparency-color-do)
- [How do I resize an animated GIF and keep transparency?](https://superuser.com/questions/1362352/how-do-i-resize-an-animated-gif-and-keep-transparency)
- [Transparency is gone while resizing (scaling) gif using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603464/transparency-is-gone-while-resizing-scaling-gif-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

overlay on transparent background:

```
ffmpeg -i 74bRi.gif -filter_complex "
color=s=256x256:d=100,format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.0[b];
[0]scale=255:144[f];
[b][f]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,split[s1][s2];
[s1]palettegen[p];
[s2][p]paletteuse
" -loop 0 output.gif
```

pad using transparent color ffffff00

```
ffmpeg -i 74bRi.gif -filter_complex "
[0]scale=255:144,pad=256:256:0:-1:ffffff00,split[s1][s2];
[s1]palettegen[p];
[s2][p]paletteuse
" -loop 0 out.gif
```